Importing NMEA RMC sentences into QGIS
I would like to import NMEA RMC datasets into QGIS (I'm using 3.28.3-Firenze). I log these on a separate measurement data logger. So far I have been able to import a .log file with GGA and RMC datasets using the QGIS option "Add vector layer". If I want to import pure NMEA RMC data, this is unfortunately not possible. However, this would make processing and logging easier for me.
Can someone tell me why I always need GGA and RMC datasets in QGIS or how I can manage to import only RMC data?
My data example:
$GPRMC,115639.30,A,4936.5717,N,00921.1721,E,1.998,2.3,281123,3.6,E,D*3F
$GPGGA,115639.30,4936.57178,N,00921.1721,E,4,35,0.8,308.15,M,48.40,M,1,2001*63


Once you've got the data imported as a vector layer you can use an SQL filter to select only the RMC sentences. Note that its not trivial to import this data since the lat-long numbers don't have a sign (plus/minus) attached to them so if you have southern or western hemisphere data you have to consider the N/S and E/W items, which I don't think QGIS will handle on import...

Are you importing your data using the GPXbabel data provider (this should show up on the add vector layer dialog)? It might be better to use a different nmea importer, such as one in the plugin library.

I'm using NMEA data that I log with PuTTY from my gnss-receiver. I looked for a NMEA importer but couldn't find one for QGIS 3.28.
